# What are the differences between CUDA compute capabilities?

Tags: cuda

What does compute capability 2.0 add over 1.3, 2.1 over 2.0, and 3.0 over 2.1?

Comment: [The relevant section of the wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUDA#Version_features_and_specifications) has a reasonably good overview.

Comment: I voted to reopen. I think the question is on topic.

Comment: The question is absolutely on topic. Voting to reopen again.

Comment: Now cuda compute capability 6.1 (as well as 6.0, 5.2) is out, and I would like to learn what's new. Voting to reopen the question to enable new answers and editing. The question is absolutely on topic and affects programming a lot: some CUDA frameworks set limits on the minimal compute capability.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The Compute Capabilities designate different architectures. In general, newer architectures run both CUDA programs and graphics faster than previous architectures. Note, though, that a high end card in a previous generation may be faster than a lower end card in the generation after.

From the CUDA C Programming Guide (v6.0):

[image: Table of Compute Capabilities]

Comment: Thanks, that helps.  It's a shame they're splitting the compute and graphics lines, as I suspect that will make the compute lines way more expensive since they'll not benefit from the cost advantages that come with being for the mass graphics market.

Comment: given this, does it make any sense to compile for a lower compute capability (eg 1.1 instead of 3.0), even if your card supports 3.0 - will it run faster?

Comment: @user1191840: Why would it run faster if you compile for an older architecture?

Comment: no idea why, but I thought that's what I observed, yet to go back and test it properly though. I thought it could be possible just because nvidia is trying to limit compute performance on later (geforce) cards, and this could be linked to compute version.

Comment: Kindly refer to the official reference of [Compute Capability](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/#features-and-technical-specifications) for more updated information.