# Caffe using GPU with NVidia Quadro 2200

Tags: cuda, gpu, nvidia, caffe

I'm using the deep learning framework [Caffe](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/) on a Ubuntu 14.04 machine. I compiled CAFE with `CPU_ONLY` option, i.e. I disabled GPU and CUDA usage. I have an NVidia Quadro K2200 graphics card and CUDA version 5.5.

I would like to know if it is possible to use Caffe with CUDA enabled with my GPU. On NVidia page, it is written that Quadro K2200 has a compute capability of 5.0. Does it mean that I can use it with CUDA versions up to release 5.0? When it is possible to use Caffe with GPU-enabled with Quadro K2200, how can I choose the appropriate CUDA version for that?

Comment: compute capability != CUDA version, see e.g. [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10961476/what-are-the-differences-between-cuda-compute-capabilities)

Answer (score 1):

CUDA version is not the same thing as Compute Capability. For one, CUDA  is current (7.5 prerelease), while CC is only at 5.2. K2200 supports CC 5.0.

The difference:

CUDA version means the library/toolkit/SDK/etc version. You should always use the highest one available.

Compute Capability is your GPU's capability to perform certain instructions, etc. Every CUDA function has a minimum CC requirement. When you write a CUDA program, it's CC requirement is the maximum of the requirements of all the features you used.

---

That said, I've no idea what Caffe is, but a quick search shows they require CC of 2.0, so you should be good to go. CC 5.0 is pretty recent, so very few things won't work on it.